# fgets doesn't wait for user input in my C code

Tags: c, csv, input, printf, fgets

I'm trying to do a simple code to write some stuff on a **.csv** file. I wrote a `for` loop and a bunch of `fgets()` to get the data from the file, but the program doesn't wait for the user to input the info and just closes the program. Does anyone have any idea on how to fix it?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>

#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#pragma warning(disable : 4996)

int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Portuguese");

    int i;
    char nome, tel, email, cpf;
    FILE *f_ptr;
    f_ptr = fopen("3556346.csv", "w+");     
    fprintf(f_ptr, "Nome, CPF, Telefone, E-mail\n");        
    
    for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        printf("Digite o nome: ");
        fgets(&nome, sizeof(nome), stdin);
        printf("Digite o CPF: ");
        fgets(&cpf, sizeof(cpf), stdin);
        printf("Digite o telefone: ");
        fgets(&tel, sizeof(tel), stdin);
        printf("Digite o e-mail: ");
        fgets(&email, sizeof(email), stdin);
        fprintf(f_ptr, "%c, %d, %c, %c\n", nome, cpf, tel, email);
    }       
    fclose(f_ptr);

    return 0;
}
```

P.S.: If anyone came here with the same problem as I had. The solution, like the nice people below pointed out, it to put `[101]` after the name of each `char` declaration. Like char `nome[101]`, `tel[101]`, ...
Also in the `fprintf` command, you should use `%s` instead of `%c`. And one last thing I found out, `fgets` stores a break line, so if you don't want it, you need to write `nome[strcspn(nome, "\n")] = '\0';` after each `fgets`, where `nome` is the name of the variable.

Comment: `char nome, tel, email, cpf;` cannot hold any string. `char nome[100]` can. (up to `99` characters plus the `'\0'` nul-terminating character) Then `fgets (nome, sizeof nome, stdin);`

Comment: Also note `#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS` and `#pragma warning(disable : 4996)` do the exact same thing, disable warning `4996`.

Comment: Thanks for your comments David. I tried to use #define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGs but it didn't work, that's why I tried the other one. But now I'm just using pragma and it's working fine. And your input about the size was all I needed to resolve my problem! Thanks again

Comment: Glad it helped. Strange about the `#define` and `#pragma` issue, they should both do exactly the same thing, see [Security Features in the CRT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/security-features-in-the-crt?view=msvc-160) Though the behavior of VS never ceases to surprise me `:)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The fgets() function reads at most one less than the number of characters specified by size from the given stream and stores them in the string str.

Since all your variables are single characters, you're asking `fgets` for single byte. It reads one less, to keep room for a termimating mull byte, which is zero.

`fgets` reads *strings* not characters. You need to store it in a string, not a character. If you want to store just one character, allocate two bytes. One for the character, one for the terminating null byte.

```
char nome[2];
fgets(nome, sizeof(nome), stdin);
```

But I suspect you want to store more than one character. You have to allocate enough memory, plus one.

```
// enough memory for 100 characters, pus the terminating null byte.
char nome[101];
fgets(nome, sizeof(nome), stdin);
```

Or, better yet, allocate a single large buffer and copy it into a properly sized amount of memory.

```
char line[4096];
printf("Digite o nome: ");
fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin);
char *nome = strdup(line);

printf("Digite o CPF: ");
fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin);
char *cpf = strdup(cpf);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Your code still gives an error, but thanks for your input I was able to correct my code. I declared a size for each char and used %s instead of %c in the fprint command.

Comment: @SamuelPereira Correct. `%c` is for a single `char` and `%s` is for "string" which is a null terminated array of characters.